The beginning of deeper mathematical abstraction

In the past, Mathematicians first created a geometric space and then thought about functions on it. For example, we defined a vector space and then thought about a linear map, defined a topological space and then thought about a continuous map. However, as time passed and functional analysis and category theory developed, the perspective of first thinking about a function space and then reconstructing a geometric space to match it developed. However, Mathematicians in 19th century wondered if it is really a feasible idea to think about a function first and then create a geometric space. Fortunately, if we look at the example of a vector space, it seems that it is really possible. In this case, the function space becomes a dual space, and if we take dual again from the function space, it becomes a double dual, so we get something that is really similar to the original space.

I'm interested in the way of thinking that goes back and forth between geometric space and functions, so I keep searching for papers on Google Scholar, but it's hard to find related content. I'm curious about what caused the order to change from the existing way of thinking that went from geometric space to functions.That is, I am curious about what triggered the change in the order of thought. For reference, I know that scheme theory was born as a result of Grothendieck thinking in the above changed order of thought.

Your mathematical mythology is cute... but... I would try not to confuse it with mathematical history.

OP, is your block quote quoted from somewhere?

You may be interested in looking at some books on the history of algebraic geometry; I vaguely remember enjoying Dieudonné's History of Algebraic Geometry, and also Parikh's The Unreal Life of Oscar Zariski.
I can't claim to be knowledgeable enough of the history to say anything definitively, and anything I can say will necessarily be highly incomplete. But my understanding is that one of the earliest motivating examples that made mathematicians want to think about some arbitrary commutative ring as the ring of functions on some hypothetical "space" was the case of number fields. There is a strong analogy between number fields and complex function fields, which can be described as the fields of meromorphic functions on, depending on taste, either Riemann surfaces or algebraic curves. For example the exponents in the prime factorization $q = \prod p_i^{e_i}$ of a rational number (so here $e_i \in \mathbb{Z}$ can be negative) are closely analogous to the orders of the zeroes and poles of a meromorphic function. This idea is called the function field analogy and can be taken very far with very fruitful results; see e.g. the nLab or MO.
The function field analogy strongly suggests that we ought to be able to think of $\mathbb{Q}$ as the "meromorphic functions" on a hypothetical space whose points are the prime numbers $p$, possibly including one additional "point at infinity," and a more general version of this for number fields. For $\mathbb{Q}$ this can be done using valuations by Ostrowski's theorem but we would really like to be able to generalize this to more complicated objects such as the set of solutions to Diophantine equations. Here an important motivation was Weil's paper where he introduced the Weil conjectures, which strongly suggested that even the apparently "discrete" world of counting solutions to equations over finite fields somehow contained highly nontrivial "topological" information (namely cohomology).
This all leads to the rich field of arithmetic geometry, which I understand to have been one of the biggest motivations for the development of scheme theory (although certainly not the only one). In scheme theory one can really write down a space $\text{Spec } \mathbb{Z}$ of primes, not just in the sense of writing down the set of primes but endowing that set with some meaningful geometry.
